# html where is best to have references to js libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that standard JS code, which will be immediately executed should be placed before body's closing tag.
But what about libraries? Where should I place e.g. reference to jQuery?

Comment: You should place jQuery before any scripts that uses jQuery, other than that, it's up to you, but placing it at the bottom right before the closing body tag, and again, before any scripts that uses jQuery, doesn't lock the browser before the HTML is outputted, so that's an advantage in most cases.

Comment: So it is better to have it  before closing tag of body, or in  header? Or it really doesn't matter? I am asking where <script src = "path_to_jquery" ... should be placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put Scripts at the Bottom** so that they load after all DOM is loaded so less time to load page content.

Put your jQuery code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Read [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)